# Halt Deploy if Token in Task List is Present

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment

I'm wondering if there is a way in Visual Studio (I have Pro at home as a Student and Web Dev 2010 Express at work) to halt a Web Deploy if a certain token is present.

I'm wondering this because I have a section of the site that uses the `[RequireHttps]` annotation that I comment out for testing, but I'm wanting a way to flag this and halt the deploy if I've added the Task List Token.

Normally I wouldn't need this and would just use the Dev ssl cert, but due to how I'm doing some of my linking this won't work.

I hope this is clear if not please ask.

An example token might be `//HALT: Uncomment [RequireHttps]` and then to stop the halt I'd simply `//HA LT: Uncomment [RequireHttps]`  If there is a better way I'm always open to suggestions.

EDIT: I don't believe this is relevant, but this is being used for a MVC3 Project.